# Do I have to choose 'All some functionality in my app is restricted' at 'App access ' in Google equipped subscription?

Tags: google-play

In case I set the subscription equipped with google play console,
first I must release the app with Closed Test.
At 'App access' in 'Set up your app' in this setting,
in case this app has subscription, it seems that I must select 'All or some
functionality in my app is restricted' in 'App access '.
Is this right?
If so, what do I have to write in the 'instruction name'?
Are the 'User name and password' needed?

I asked this question to the google support, but they said that this is the question they cannot answer.